# Ambiguity with tidyverse filter( %in% )

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I ran into an annoying issue earlier today where I had a dataframe with hundreds of columns that I had been given. I was then attempting to select rows from this dataframe using a list I had created using a different process. When I attempted to filter using the list, I got a blank dataframe in return. After struggling with this for awhile I realized that the massive dataframe I was selecting from also had a column with the same name as my list, and that my filter action was usinig this as priority.

My question is, is there a better way I should be filtering from dataframes rather than the way I am currently? I do not like that it is ambiguous if a column or a list is used. Here is a minimum example to show this:

Consider a dataframe which has two columns, a and b:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(a = c("first", "second", "third"),
       b = c("2", "3", "4"))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#  a      b    
#  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 first  2    
# 2 second 3    
# 3 third  4
```

I would then like to select rows from this dataframe using a list of values I created using a different process. Notice that the first list is named b, which is also the name of one of the columns in the df.

```
b = c("first")
d = c("first")
```

These two commands are almost the same, except that the first filters based on the column (and therefore returns nothing) and the second filters based on the list(and therefore returns the first row):

```
# Returns Nothing:
df %>%
  filter(a %in% b)
# # A tibble: 0 × 2
# … with 2 variables: a <chr>, b <chr>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names

# Returns Desired Row(s)
df %>%
  filter(a %in% d)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
#  a     b    
#  <chr> <chr>
# 1 first 2
```

Is there a better way to filter which is less ambiguous? I guess I would like an error or something like that. I realize this is kind of an edge case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `!!` to evaluate the vector `b`, rather than use the variable `b` from the dataset.  It also works with vectors that are not also variable names in the data, like `d`.  So, if you imagined this happening a lot, you could always prefix the vector of values you're filtering on with `!!` and you won't run unto this problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(a = c("first", "second", "third"),
            b = c("2", "3", "4"))

b = c("first")
d = c("first")

df %>%
  filter(a %in% !!b)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   a     b    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 first 2

df %>%
  filter(a %in% !!d)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   a     b    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 first 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can use .data$ and.env$ from rlang to distinguish between the variable in the data set and the object in the environment.

```
df %>%
    filter(a %in% .env$b)

A tibble: 1 × 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 first 2
```